# Error saving record CKRecordID to server: invalid attempt to update record from type 'X' to 'Y'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit, ckmodifyrecordsoperation, ckerror

While I'm using `CKModifyRecordsOperation` to save records for multiple tables to Private Cloud Database's Default Zone, it always return the error below except table 'X':

> Error saving record  to server: invalid attempt to update record from type 'X' to 'Y'

The `error.userInfo` detail:

> {
>       CKErrorDescription = "Error saving record CKRecordID: 0x7fd7a3d4c0c0; 1:(_defaultZone:**defaultOwner**) to server: invalid attempt to update record from type 'X' to 'Y'";
>       ContainerID = "iCloud.com...";
>       NSDebugDescription = "CKInternalErrorDomain: 2006";
>       NSLocalizedDescription = "Error saving record  to server: invalid attempt to update record from type 'X' to 'Y'";
>       NSUnderlyingError = "CKError 0x7fa0d250c4e0: \"Invalid Arguments\" (2006); server message = \"invalid attempt to update record from type 'X' to 'Y'\"; uuid = E2E...D1E; container ID = \"iCloud.com...\"";
>       RequestUUID = "E2E...D1E";
>       ServerErrorDescription = "invalid attempt to update record from type 'X' to 'Y'";
>       errorKey = ck1rosofi;
>   }

Related code snippets:

```
- (void)sync
{
  ...
  NSMutableArray * operations;
  for (NSString *tableName in @[@"X", @"Y"]) {
    CKModifyRecordsOperation * operation = [self _modifyRecordsOperationWithTableName:tableName];
    if (operation) {
      if (operations) [operations addObject:operation];
      else operations = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:operation];
    }
  }

  if (operations) {
    [operationQueue addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
  }
}

- (CKModifyRecordsOperation *)_modifyRecordsOperationWithTableName:(NSString *)tableName
{
  ...

  NSMutableArray * recordsToSave = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (KYModel <KYModel_iCloudProtocol> *instance in unsyncedInstances) {
    CKRecordID * objectID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:@(instance.id).stringValue];
    CKRecord * cloudRecord = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType:tableName recordID:objectID];
    ... setup record detail
    [recordsToSave addObject:record];
  }

  CKModifyRecordsOperation * operation = [[CKModifyRecordsOperation alloc] initWithRecordsToSave:recordsToSave recordIDsToDelete:nil];
  operation.database = [[CKContainer defaultContainer] privateCloudDatabase];
  operation.savePolicy = CKRecordSaveAllKeys;
  operation.qualityOfService = NSQualityOfServiceUserInteractive;
  operation.atomic = NO;
  operation.perRecordProgressBlock = ...;
  operation.perRecordCompletionBlock = ^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
      // got error here
    }
    ...
  };
  operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = ...;

  return operation;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching & debugging for a while, I realised that those failed records have same "Record Name" (it's an unique name for `CKRecordID`, which likes an unique ID for each record) already in the same zone, though they're belonging to different tables.

---

#### Solution One:

**Making CKRecordID's "Record Name" Unique Among All Tables**.

For example, add a table name prefix for each record name: [table_name]_[id].

The problem of my case above is that "Record Name" duplicated for records of different tables in same zone (Default Zone).

And with `CKModifyRecordsOperation`'s `CKRecordSaveAllKeys` saving policy, when save record (id:1) for table Y, it finds another record (id:1) of table X at Cloud, and tries to modify it, which throws the error *"invalid attempt to update record from type 'X' to 'Y'"* at last.

---

#### Solution Two:

**Creating Custom Zones for Each Table** (Note: Custom Zone is only available for Private Cloud Database).

For example, instead of using the Default Zone, use custom zone "X_Zone" for table X, and "Y_Zone" for table Y. Then we can keep using @"id" as CKRecordID's "Record Name".

In this way, you need to provide the `zoneID` as well when convert your local record to CKRecord instance:

```
CKRecordZoneID *zoneID = [[CKRecordZoneID alloc] initWithZoneName:@"Custom_Zone_Name_Here"
                                                         ownerName:CKOwnerDefaultName];
CKRecordID *objectID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:@(instance.id).stringValue zoneID:zoneID];
...
```

And of course, you need to create the related custom zone first:

```
CKRecordZone *zone = [[CKRecordZone alloc] initWithZoneName:@"Custom_Zone_Name"];
[[[CKContainer defaultContainer] privateCloudDatabase] saveRecordZone:zone completionHandler:...];
```

or create multiple at same time:

```
NSMutableArray *zones = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *zoneName in @[...]) {
  CKRecordZone *zone = [[CKRecordZone alloc] initWithZoneName:zoneName];
  [zones addObject:zone];
}
CKModifyRecordZonesOperation * operation = [[CKModifyRecordZonesOperation alloc] initWithRecordZonesToSave:zones recordZoneIDsToDelete:nil];
...
[[[CKContainer defaultContainer] privateCloudDatabase] addOperation:operation];
```

---

I've tested both & works as expected.

---

#### Suggestion:

If your records are stored in Private Cloud Database, I think the Solution Two will be a good choice, as the DOC said:

> ... Use custom zones to arrange and encapsulate groups of related records in the private database. Custom zones support other capabilities too, such as the ability to write multiple records as a single atomic transaction.

> Treat each custom zone as a single unit of data that is separate from every other zone in the database. Inside the zone, you add records as you would anywhere else.
> ...

It'll be much more convenient to handle records for each table, like deleting the zone for table instead of querying & deleting records for the table in same zone.

**BUT NOTE**, if you use `CKReference` among tables, DO NOT use custom zones for those tables then, cause

> ... the CKReference class does not support cross-zone linking, so each reference object must point to a record in the same zone as the current record.

---

*Btw, this's the answer for the Self-Answered-Question, hope it helps if someone else get the same issue. Please point it out if there's something wrong in my answer, and welcome any suggestion as well, thx in advance.* :)